# How can I connect from an external source to a Logstash service hosted in a docker / rancher container

Tags: docker, logstash, elastic-stack, rancher

Need some help us with a Rancher / Docker issue encountered while trying to set up Logstash to parse our IIS logs.

There’s a container with 1 service **Logstash** (not a web service but a system service, part of the ELK stack that we want to use to ingests files from a given input(s) and parse them into fields before sending them to the configured output(s) – in this case, Elasticsearch).

We need to have the service accessible from an outside system (namely our web server which is going to send the IIS logs over for processing).

> The problem is that we can’t get the endpoint configuration.

There is a load balancer host running on `rancher` with two open ports that are supposed to channel all requests to the inner services containers via path name and target but we can’t get a path configured to the logstash service.

I have been digging into the logstash configs and there is a setting for node.name in the `logstash.conf` file but … I haven’t managed to do anything with it yet.

Hoping someone who is more familiar with this stuff can offer some insight.
**Basically I can get the Logstash service on Rancher to connect to the AWS Elasticsearch but I cannot get our web box (with the IIS logs) to connect with the Logstash service on its input port.**

Answer (score 0):

Solution was not to use the standard image but customize it. steps involved:

- create local repo with folder structure that we need to emulate. Only
  the folders we are going to replace are needed
- add a dockerfile which will be used to build up the image from a docker run command
- in the dockerfile reference the ready-made / standard image as a base in the first line, i.e. 'FROM '
- in the dockerfile RUN command remove the directories and files that need to be customized. In this case it was logstash/pipeline
  directory and logstash/config directory
- use ADD commands to replace the missing directories with our customized versions
- use EXPOSE command to expose the port the service is listening on
- Build the container using docker run and the -p flag to publish the ports we want open, mapping them to ports on the host container